# Android activity has one fragment ,I want to call another from this fragment , how can I achieve this

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `activity` **RegistrationActivity**

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);



    }
```

In this class there is a fragment **RegistrationActivityFragment**

```
    public class RegistrationActivityFragment extends Fragment {

Button b1;
EditText et1;

public RegistrationActivityFragment() {
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_details, container, false);
    b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.nameNext);
    et1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_register_details_name);
    showInputMethod();
    et1.requestFocus();
    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            enableSubmitIfReady();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    b1.setEnabled(false);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EducationalDetailsActivityFragment nextFrag= new EducationalDetailsActivityFragment();
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(b1.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    return v;


}


public void showInputMethod() {

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}


public void enableSubmitIfReady() {

    boolean isReady =et1.getText().toString().length()>3;
    if(isReady){
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deeppurple500));


    }
    else{
        b1.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

this is the fragments layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragregistrationname"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="We're setting up your profile.     Lets begin with the introduction"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reg_details_name_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/regdetailsnamecolor"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/greyback"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="#bcbec0"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fragment_register_details_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="FULL NAME"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="#bcbec0" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nameNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonDisabledback"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="1/4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to star this fragment on click from the fragment above

```
public class EducationalDetailsActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public EducationalDetailsActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_educational_details2, container, false);
        Button b1= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.eduNext);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MaleFemaleRegistrationActivityFragment nextFrag= new MaleFemaleRegistrationActivityFragment();
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragEducational, nextFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

            }
        });

        return v;

    }
```

this is the second fragment's layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragEducational" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Hi Kaustubh , tell us a little about your.."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reg_details_name_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Educational Qualifications"
        android:textColor="@color/regdetailsnamecolor"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/greyback"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="Bachelors"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/on_off_switch"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="MAsters"
                android:textOn="Bachelors"/>

            <TextView
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="Masters"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eduNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/deeppurple500"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="2/4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my Activity's layout activity_registration

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.purplesq.purplesq.activities.RegistrationActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration" >

</fragment>
```

Comment: Please show your activites xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have given wrong id (R.id.fragEducational) in EducationalDetailsActivityFragment onClick().you should replace it with id (R.id.fragment) as in the below code.

```
MaleFemaleRegistrationActivityFragment nextFrag= new MaleFemaleRegistrationActivityFragment();
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment, nextFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can do this.But fragment will replace on your RegistrationActivity layout.You forgot to add this activity layout(activity_registration).Can you add this layout.So i can implement other part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take FrameLayout in your RegistrationActivity, so you can inflate fragments into it. Like this:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>
```

After that on click of any widget call:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new EducationalDetailsActivityFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat -great.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're looking for is this :

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction =
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
 transaction.commit();
```

where R.id.fragment_container is the id of your activity's FrameLayout where you've load your first fragment, and 'fragment' is your new fragment.
You've got to call this in your activity so you'll have to create a public method that is doing it and calling it from your fragment :

```
((RegistrationActivity) getActivity()).yourPublicMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can i propose you.lıke this.
You can add to otto library.It likes iterfaces.it so easy using.According to me wrong call activity method from fragment.We have two way 
Firstly 
You can use fragmentIteractionListener.Secondly you can use otto library.[otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Otto is so helper.If you need more help i can.